# On click delete table row in Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have this code Ajax/Jquery that creates a dynamic table with rows based on data retrieved from the database. When creating the table buttons are also created dynamically for each row.
In addition to the above I would like to be able to call a function for thees buttons. For example if the first table row button has an id of 0, then clicking on button with id 0 will call a function that would take the id of the first row, and perform a database delete function.
How can I achieve this?

Here is my code where the table is created dynamically:

```
success: function(controller_data)
              {     JSON.stringify(controller_data);

                        var tr;
                        for (var i = 0; i < controller_data.length; i++) {

                            tr = $('<tr/>');
                  tr.append("<td><input name = \"radios\" value = tablebutton"+i+" id=tablebutton"+i+" type=\"button\"></td>");
                            tr.append("<td>" + controller_data[i].id + "</td>");
                            tr.append("<td>" + controller_data[i].question + "</td>");
                            tr.append("<td>" + controller_data[i].image + "</td>");
                            tr.append("<td>" + controller_data[i].answer1 + "</td>");
                            tr.append("<td>" + controller_data[i].answer2 + "</td>");
                            tr.append("<td>" + controller_data[i].answer3 + "</td>");
                            tr.append("<td>" + controller_data[i].answer4 + "</td>");
                            $('table').append(tr);
                              }
              }
```

[image]

Comment: Event delegation: [Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

Comment: @Andreas Maybe I can do it like this: assign the ID value that is displayed as the ID of the TD. The when calling the .on click function check what is the TD ID value and get that value to delete the specific database row. Will it work?

Comment: That should work. I've added a slightly different solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use event delegation **[on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)** since you deal with fresh DOM added dynamically to the page, e.g :

```
$('body').on('click', 'input[id^="tablebutton"]', function(){
     //Call your function
})
```

Try to add `class` to identify `td` that contain row id e.g :

```
tr.append("<td class='row-id'>" + controller_data[i].id + "</td>");
```

**Full code :**

```
$(function(){ //Ready function
     $('body').on('click', 'input[id^="tablebutton"]', function(){
         var row_id = $(this).parents('tr').find('.row-id').text(); //get the id
         myFunction(row_id);
     })
})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It does help, now I am just trying to understand where all the code goes as I am new to Jquery.

Comment: Do you have 1min to go on chat?

Answer (score 0):

This would be the delegated event handler registered on the next suitable parent node which would be the `<table>` (imho)

```
$("table").on("click", "input.delete", function() {
    var rowId = $(this).val();

    // delete row in backend...
});
```

But this will only work with the restructured `success` handler below:

```
success : function (controller_data) {
    var rows = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < controller_data.length; i++) {
        rows.push('<tr>'
                    + '<td><input class="delete" name="radios" value="' + i + '" type="button"></td>'
                    + '<td>' + controller_data[i].id + '</td>'
                    + '<td>' + controller_data[i].question + '</td>'
                    + '<td>' + controller_data[i].image + '</td>'
                    + '<td>' + controller_data[i].answer1 + '</td>'
                    + '<td>' + controller_data[i].answer2 + '</td>'
                    + '<td>' + controller_data[i].answer3 + '</td>'
                    + '<td>' + controller_data[i].answer4 + '</td>'
                + '</tr>';
    }

    $("table").append(rows.join(""));
}
```

I've removed the useless `JSON.stringify(...)` call, and changed the for loop a little bit to only change the DOM once per request instead of once per row.
I've also added the class `delete` to the `<input />` for a more descriptive selector.
And last but not least the `value` is now the id only instead of `tablebutton<id>`.